# Getting an element in Javascript - but what element # is it within the document?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a set of  elements that, on click, I want to change colour. Now, I have a colour assigned to each of them (ie, if it's the first one in the list then this colour, if it's the second then a different colour...) but how do I check which one they are? Like, if I click on the third, how do I know it was the third? Is there a javascript method for it or even a jQuery method?

Thanks

Comment: Please show a sample of your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has an [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method, that should do what you want.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/au2fQ/

---

HTML

```
<ul id="Test">
    <li>Click Me</li>
    <li>Click Me</li>
</ul>
<ul id="Test2">
    <li>Click Me 2</li>
    <li>Click Me 2</li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$('li', '#Test,#Test2').click(function(){
    var i = $(this).index(),
        k = $(this).index('li');
    alert('This is li '+i+' in the ul.  This is li '+k+' in the page.');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

If they're siblings:

```
$(this).index();
```

This returns a 0-based index, so the third is `2`.

If they're not siblings, cache the set:

```
var els = $('.my_group_of_elements');
```

Then do this:

```
els.index( this );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I eventually used $(this).index('canvas'); but I'll keep your answer in mind in case I need to use it in the future!

Comment: @KerrM: You're welcome. Keep in mind that `$(this).index('canvas');` will perform a DOM selection for all `canvas` elements every time. Unless the number of canvas elements will change, it would be more efficient to cache the set, and do `canvases.index( this )`. Just something to remember. :)